# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube$Builder

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am working on YouTube WatchMe for Android project which is available on github

[Click Here:](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme)

**What I have tried?**

1] I downloaded & imported project in eclipse.

2] Downloaded & imported all required JARs in `libs` folder

**Where I got stuck?**

When I call below line of code

```
        YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory,
                credential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                .build();
```

For this YouTube class, I imported

> google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev126-1.19.1.jar

jar file. But the problem is the above line throws below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube$Builder
```

I don't know why I am facing this issue. I have gone through all the ways of importing JAR in eclipse but was unable to to get it worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34419/2811956

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5756989/2811956

Comment: Thanks for sharing link. But that jar file contains inner class Builder & which is not getting fetched. Please see my question carefully.